# Does UTF-8 use same amount of memory as UTF-32 when pushed on the stack?

Tags: assembly, unicode, utf-8, x86, nasm

The question is specifically about how much space UTF-8 occupies on the stack and therefore in memory (RAM), as in: is it the same as UTF-32? So this is not about how much disk space UTF-8 takes when serialized to a file. Sorry if that attempt at disambiguation insulted your intellect.

- stack is always in RAM. So anything I put on stack occupies space in RAM.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433390/is-stack-in-cpu-or-ram#:~:text=Stack%20is%20always%20in%20RAM,at%20the%20top%20of%20stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433390/is-stack-in-cpu-or-ram#:%7E:text=Stack%20is%20always%20in%20RAM,at%20the%20top%20of%20stack).

- stack is at least 32 bits on x86 and 64 bits on x86_64. So whether I push one-byte chars or three-byte chars onto stack, they all take at least 32 bits in memory. I imagine this is what happens with UTF-32, that it takes 32 bits on stack.

[How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif)

So, what do they mean when they say UTF-32 takes more memory than UTF-8 ?

**Edit**

> UTF-32 uses more memory, but today's computers are equipped with a lot
> of memory. The pressure to save memory is gone and the simple and fast
> handling of UTF-32 strings outweighs the increased memory usage. Using
> UTF-32 leads to faster programs than any approach that tries to save
> memory by examining strings.

https://seed7.sourceforge.net/faq.htm#unicode

Comment: Thankyou. I was just reading your other post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134007/1056010

Comment: Would it be fair to say, UTF-32 helps with woth performance without any penalty w.r.t memory usage ? Edited the question with more detail.

Comment: Was already expanding my comment into an answer.

Comment: Note: your question is go in very details, but in practical uses: either you uses strings as black box, so just care about a string, and possible in heap (if string can be large it is a must), or you are doing *Unicode things* and you will realize that there is elsewhere huge amount of CPU and memory, so it doesn't matter much. (UTF-8 is mostly optimized for first case, so compatible with old ASCIIZ strings).

Comment: In UTF-8, it sometimes takes multiple code units (bytes) to represent 1 code point (character), so a given text in UTF-8 has the same or more code units than in UTF-32.  Thus, pushing them on the stack where each code unit occupies a fixed size (e.g. 8 bytes) means that the UTF-8 version will take the same or more space than the UTF-32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the weird case where you `push` multiple separate UTF-8 coding units (bytes), yes that would use 8 bytes of stack space per byte of UTF-8 data.  But only in that case.

That's horribly inefficient, which is why **people don't write code that way** (except for some simplistic beginner examples of using the stack to reverse a short string, as a learning exercise for understanding the LIFO ordering of push/pop).

If you want to store string data in stack space, you'd reserve some space (like a local `char` array) and use it, not unpacking bytes or dwords to qwords.  Like `sub rsp, 64+8` / `movdqu xmm0, [rsi]` / `movdqa [rsp], xmm0` to copy 16 bytes (of UTF-32 or UTF-8 data, doesn't matter which).

If you really want to use push, you could `push qword [rdi+rcx]` to copy 8 bytes at a time while pushing, counting backwards from the end of the source string so the string ends up on the stack in the same order as the source.

When you access the data, you can use `mov eax, [rsp + rcx*4]` for UTF-32 (or preferably a pointer increment, but the scale factor helps illustrate the addressing).  Or for UTF-8, `movzx eax, byte [rsp + rcx]` (with a loop to check for multi-byte characters and potentially load more bytes, if you want to get a unicode code-point into EAX).  Unpacking each byte of UTF-8 to 8 bytes makes zero sense, and makes it *harder* to efficiently handle multi-byte characters.  e.g. with an 8-byte load and BMI2 `pext` to pack, and maybe `andn` / `tzcnt` / `bzhi` to find the end of the multi-byte character (a byte with its high bit clear) and zero the garbage above it.

---

**For normal ways to handle string data** (keeping it packed the same way as on disk), **UTF-8 is 4x smaller than UTF-32 for the ASCII subset of Unicode.**  For Western languages with some 2 and 3-byte accented characters but still mostly 1-byte characters, it's still a lot smaller.  For languages where most characters are 3 or more bytes long in UTF-8, UTF-32 doesn't take much more space.  (And expanding each byte of UTF-8 to 8 bytes vs. each dword of UTF-32 would make UTF-8 take way *more* space.)

It can make sense to convert to UTF-32 on input and back to UTF-8 on output.  Then we're back to the good old days where a character has a fixed size so array indexing can give us the nth character (modulo Unicode shenanigans separate from the variable-length encodings like UTF-8 and UTF-16).  This does increase space usage, including cache footprint, especially for Western languages.  RAM is cheap, but cache footprint and memory bandwidth aren't.  So this isn't always the best strategy.

Comment: " And expanding each byte of UTF-8 to 8 bytes vs. each dword of UTF-32 would make UTF-8 take way more space. " but whether they are one byte characters or four byte characters, they all occupy 64 bits, right ? Or do we have a way to use that empty space with out explicitly doing it ? Some way of optimizing perhaps.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: The point of my answer is that normal code doesn't do that.  `push 'a'` / `push 'b'` / .. isn't useful, neither is `movzx eax, byte [rsi]` / `push rax` / `movzx eax, byte [rsi+1]` / `push rax`.  You *could* waste vast amounts of space that way if you wanted to, making UTF-8 *larger* than UTF-32, but why?  If you're going to do any processing, the useful thing is to decode UTF-8 to 32-bit unicode code-points (UTF-32) on input so you don't have to keep dealing with multi-byte characters.

Comment: Ok, so then the UTF-32 does indeed not have any penalty w.r.t memory utilization. Thankyou sir.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: For that insane way of storing data, yes, UTF-32 would be smaller (or the same size with no multi-byte UTF-8 characters).  But it makes zero sense to say "UTF-32 has no space penalty" as a general statement without the specific context of your unpacking scheme.  The most important point of my answer is that nobody stores character data that way in sane programs, so it's not a useful thing to compare.  Your last comment  seems like an attempt to TL:DR my answer into completely the wrong message.

Comment: Oh apologies , I don't an have agenda here. I was trying to write an rudimentary program which decodes utf-8 using nasm. I was pushing single bytes onto stack. That made me wonder if I am doing it right or if there are ways to store multiple characters in each 8 byte. Thanks again, I will read your answer more throughly and wil also lookup "unpacking scheme"

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: "unpacking scheme" isn't a technical term, just an English phrase to describe something like expanding each byte (or character?) to a qword.  And yes, there are ways to store multiple character per 8 bytes... for example UTF-32 stores each character in 4 bytes, so 2 characters per 8 bytes.  If you don't know how to make arrays with element sizes other than 8 bytes, look at optimized C compiler output, e.g.  https://godbolt.org/z/rsbj3YdWf uses a `char` array. ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))